# How to reinitialize an array?

Tags: c#, arrays

So I have this array initialized:

```
string[] names = { "Joe", "Bob", "", "", "Marcus", "" };
```

Now I want to change the contents in a similar manner. I tried:

```
names = {"Happy", "", "", "Go", "", "Lucky"};
```

but this results in the error,

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Is there a way to bulk-assign the contents of an array like I am trying to do?

Comment: :) http://www.dotnetperls.com/array

Answer (score 5):

The raw `{ ... }` syntax can only be used when declaring the array.

To create a new array instance, use `new string[] { ... }`.  You can then assign this new array instance to the variable:

```
names = new string[] {"Happy", "", "", "Go", "", "Lucky"};
```

Note that the old array instance will not be affected.

Comment: names[0] = "Happy";
names[3] = "Go";
names[5] = "Happy";